# Google Forms createResponse with date decrements the day by 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I am programmatically generating new form responses from rows of data in a Google Sheet (one approval workflow system generates new approval requests in a second approval workflow system). The data includes dates. My script takes the date value as a string from a cell, converts it into a native JavaScript date object, then submits this to a new form response using createResponse(). Here's the pertinent code:

```
var startDate = googleFormsDateStringToDate(eventDetails['Event Start Date']);
var r = item.createResponse(startDate);
```

For the most part, the system works robustly. Except for one intriguing problem - for any date **after** 29/04/2020, the date stored in the response is decremented by 1 day. Any date on or before this date works as expected, any date after is decremented by a day.

I have tried a few things.

The dates correspond to a start date and end date for an event. If the start date is before this date and the end date after, the end date will be decremented whilst the start date is recorded accurately. So I am certain the issue is directly related to whether the date I am submitting falls before or after this date.

I have tested extensively and am absolutely certain that the string-date conversion is working. If I retrieve the value of the response **immediately** after creating it (before the form response is even submitted), I find that it has been decremented:

```
var startDate = dateStringToDate(eventDetails['Event Start Date']);
Logger.log(startDate.toString()); // startDate is always accurate
var r = item.createResponse(startDate);
Logger.log(r.getResponse()); // if after 29/04/2020, will be decremented by 1 day
```

This tells me the issue is occurring precisely when I create the response and that it is occurring "at Google's end".

One of my suspicions is that it may be a timezone issue, but that would not explain why the issue is linked directly to this specific date. My other suspicion is that it may be to do with the fact that 2020 is a leap year, so we get 29/02/2020, and the date after which the error occurs is 29/03/2020. Perhaps somewhere behind Google's implementation of createResponse it is failing to account for the leap year?

Until I can identify the error, I plan to implement a workaround in which I will use getResponse() to check if the response date matches the intended date and correct accordingly. But I would prefer to understand what is causing the error (so I know if it is a bug requiring reporting, or simply my lack of understanding) and, if possible, find a solution.

So, specific questions: What is the source of the error? Is there a solution (rather than a workaround)?

**EDIT**
Whilst figuring out a workaround, I have answered my first question. In the UK, daylight savings time starts on 29/04/2020. Since the dates entered via the Google Form have no time associated with them, the time appears to be stored as 00:00:00, or midnight. I assume that what is happening is that the adjustment for daylight savings time (1 hour) is subtracting an hour from this time, thereby rolling it back to the day before.

My final question stands: is there a means to reliably prevent this error from occurring rather than manually checking for inaccurate dates (or programming in daylight savings time dates)?

Comment: Have you checked the spreadsheet / script timezone settings? Sometimes date discrepancies are be caused by those.

Comment: Good thought - I hadn't checked that. I can verify that my script and the associated Spreadsheet are set to GMT+00:00 (I haven't changed that). In the script and sheet the times appear to be accurate. It is specifically when I createResponse that it changes, leading me to think it is something to do with the timezone for the form itself. I cannot find any means to check the timezone of the form specifically. However, the response Sheet associated with the form is also GMT+00:00.